# Build error androidx.media.session.MediaButtonReceiver: Targeting S+ (version 31 and above)

Tags: android, flutter, build

I tried to run my flutter application on Android 12.0 API 31

It fail with error

```
adb: failed to install \build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app.apk: Failure [INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_MANIFEST_MALFORMED: Failed parse during
installPackageLI: /data/app/vmdl1793799027.tmp/base.apk (at Binary XML file line #370): androidx.media.session.MediaButtonReceiver: Targeting S+ (version 31 and above) requires that an 
explicit value for android:exported be defined when intent filters are present]
Error launching application on sdk gphone64 x86 64.
```

It is working fine on API 28.

My AndroidManifest.xml has following

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.ktcglobal.ktcmap">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION" />
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />

    <queries>
        <!-- If your app opens https URLs -->
        <intent>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"  />
            <data android:scheme="https" />
        </intent>

    </queries>
   <application
        android:label="JanakaAPP"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher">
          <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
            android:value="090909" />
        <service
            android:name="MyNavigationService"
            android:foregroundServiceType="location">    
        </service>
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
        
        
            <meta-data
              android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.NormalTheme"
              android:resource="@style/NormalTheme"
              />

            <meta-data
              android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.SplashScreenDrawable"
              android:resource="@drawable/launch_background"
              />
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <meta-data
            android:name="flutterEmbedding"
            android:value="2" />

       <provider
        android:name="vn.hunghd.flutterdownloader.DownloadedFileProvider"
        android:authorities="${applicationId}.flutter_downloader.provider"
        android:exported="false"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true">
    <meta-data
        android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
        android:resource="@xml/provider_paths"/>
    </provider>

    <!-- Begin FlutterDownloader customization -->
    <!-- disable default Initializer -->
    <provider
        android:name="androidx.startup.InitializationProvider"
        android:authorities="${applicationId}.androidx-startup"
        android:exported="false"
        tools:node="merge">
        <meta-data
            android:name="androidx.work.WorkManagerInitializer"
            android:value="androidx.startup"
            tools:node="remove" />
    </provider>

    <!-- declare customized Initializer -->
    <provider
        android:name="vn.hunghd.flutterdownloader.FlutterDownloaderInitializer"
        android:authorities="${applicationId}.flutter-downloader-init"
        android:exported="false">
        <!-- changes this number to configure the maximum number of concurrent tasks -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="vn.hunghd.flutterdownloader.MAX_CONCURRENT_TASKS"
            android:value="5" />
    </provider>
    <!-- End FlutterDownloader customization -->
    </application>
</manifest>
```

I have search online has there are several reference to add

```
android:exported="true"
```

would solve this issue.

As I can see it is already in there. Are there other places I have to add it?

The libs I used in pubspec.yamel are;

```
  provider: ^5.0.0
  google_maps_flutter: ^2.0.6
  geolocator: ^7.0.3
  geocoding: ^2.0.0  
  flutter_polyline_points: ^1.0.0
  dio: ^4.0.0
  location: ^4.2.0
  fluttertoast: ^8.0.7
  http: ^0.13.3
  http_parser: ^4.0.0
  flutter_sound: ^8.2.5
  maps_toolkit: ^2.0.0
  intl: ^0.17.0
  shared_preferences: ^2.0.6
  image_picker: ^0.8.3+2
  country_code_picker: ^2.0.2
  expansion_tile_card: ^2.0.0
  url_launcher: ^6.0.10  
  vector_math: 2.1.1
  firebase_core: ^1.1.0
  firebase_messaging: ^11.2.6
  overlay_support: ^1.2.1  
  flutter_downloader: ^1.7.3  
  path_provider: ^2.0.9
  permission_handler: ^9.2.0
  device_info: ^2.0.3
  just_audio: ^0.9.21
  uuid: ^3.0.6
  byte_array: ^0.1.6
  qrscan: ^0.3.2
```

Is there anything else I should be adding to get this working?

Any help would be apricated.

Answer (score 0):

Because It's deprecated do not use it. If you didn't use bluetooth microphone module then you can just use MediaSession.